# Klau KVM Switch 2 PC 3 Monitors, Low Resolution Issue with One Monitor

Tags: graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, resolution, kvm-switch

I have this KVM ([https://www.amazon.com/CKLau-Multi-Monitor-KVM-Switch/dp/B08BCFSHWL?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08BCFSHWL)) to switch between work and home PCs.

Computer A, macbook pro, works fine. Everything is connected, all monitors have their resolutions set correctly as if they were connected directly to the macbook. Computer B, PC running windows 10 with RTX geforce 2070 graphics card one of the monitors can only display resolutions in 1024x768@60 hz or lower settings, the other monitors are fine at whatever resolution setting. I've verified that:

- Display port cables are fine (switched inputs and outputs with different set of DP cables)
- Drivers are updated, Nvdia drivers are up-to-date as well as any window drivers currently using
- Used different ports from KVM. Computer A - no impact, Computer B always the same problem.
- Monitor in question is the Z321QU Acer Predator series.
- Monitor above works fine with the computer A and KVM, just not with computer B and KVM.
- EDIT: Also tried the classic "turn it on and off again", monitors, PCs, KVM switch, everything. Issue persists.

I'm wondering why increasing the resolution causes my monitor to display "no signal", is this a limitation with the KVM switch or something else wrong with the interactions between computer B, KVM and Acer monitor or something like an EDID issue where monitor isn't relaying correct information through the KVM?

Comment: well written question! I have one for you. Did you try connecting the PC to the problem monitor directly with no KVM switch? If so what were the results?

Comment: I did in fact, as a temporary workaround. I have my PC connected directly to the monitor via hdmi cable and tested with DP cable as well, no problems. I think(?) it has something to do with the KVM switch not relaying proper signal/information to the monitor, I'm not sure what else is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Acer Predator monitors are very picky in GPU matching.
We found if we having issue with some GPU, then after we change te DP version on the monitor from DP 1.4 to DP 1.2, most of issues can be solved.

I suspected that the DP 1.4 core with Preadtor monitors (specially for 4K 120hz models) are using different IC chip sets than its other monitor lines.